# New to ASP..<%@ Page Language="" %>

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have recently decided to dive in to ASP and have set up a Windows Server package on my resellers account (shared hosting).

I'm from a largely PHP background and haven't touched ASP since, well, tonight.

I created a new file in Dreamweaver (hey, I like the colourful syntax) and was presented with a choice of filetypes:

- ASP Javascript (file.**asp**)
- ASP VBScript (file.**asp**)
- ASP C# (file.**aspx**)
- ASP VB (file.**aspx**)

Could someone better informed please tell me why some files are `.asp` and others are `.aspx`?

I'm aware that the ASP framework supports JS/C#/VB (I think!) but what does this mean in laymen's...that a developer may use a language of their choice within ASP pages?

Also, Dreamweaver added:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

to the top of my page, which, when I uploaded caused a Runtime error. (My hosting was unable to show any errors except for the generic one).

Removing this top line, and my code seems to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<%Response.Write("My first ASP script!")%>
</body>
</html>
```

Any clarification would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asp`  is the "old" Active Service Page and `aspx` is ASP.NET. I recommend you dive into the tutorials over at [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/learn), the videos are really great and easy to understand.

I would also recommend going for [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) which is a bit easier to understand if you are use php development.

Comment: the videos certainly look promising. Looks like I'll be diving in to ASP.NET then. thanks!

Comment: @calum, no problem! :) Don't forget to upvote / accept answers that you see fit. Good luck with asp.net.

Comment: I'm not quite reputable enough yet so you'll have to just accept a tick !

Answer (score 1):

We are stuck with an old ASP classic application at work. PLEASE start with ASP.NET.
You will never regret it. ASP is an old technology with a lot less possibilities than ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If your writing ASP and Not ASP.NET then you want ASP VBScript  or ASP Javascript. ASP.net is a totally different beast. It would be like comparing PHP to Java.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`*.aspx` is Asp.NET, which has been Microsoft's flagship for the last 10 years.  `*.asp` is the "old" ASP, now called "Classic ASP", which was in use before Asp.NET was introduced.